# Python 3 concurrent.futures: How to add back failed futures to ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I've a list of urls to download via concurrent.futures's ThreadPoolExecutor, but there may be some timeout urls which I want to re-download them after all first tries are over. I don't know how to do it, here is my try, but failed with endless printing 'time_out_again':

```
import concurrent.futures

def player_url(url):
    # here. if timeout, return 1. otherwise do I/O and return 0.
    ...

urls = [...]
time_out_futures = [] #list to accumulate timeout urls
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    future_to_url = (executor.submit(player_url, url) for url in urls)
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        if future.result() == 1:
            time_out_futures.append(future)

# here is what I try to deal with all the timeout urls       
while time_out_futures:
    future = time_out_futures.pop()
    if future.result() == 1:
        print('time_out_again')
        time_out_futures.insert(0,future)   # add back to the list
```

So, is there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Future` objects can only be used once. The `Future` itself doesn't know anything about the function its returning the result for - the `ThreadPoolExecutor` object is responsible for creating the `Future`, returning it, and running the function in the background:

```
def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    with self._shutdown_lock:
        if self._shutdown:
            raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after shutdown')

        f = _base.Future()
        w = _WorkItem(f, fn, args, kwargs)

        self._work_queue.put(w)
        self._adjust_thread_count()
        return f

class _WorkItem(object):
    def __init__(self, future, fn, args, kwargs):
        self.future = future
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        if not self.future.set_running_or_notify_cancel():
            return

        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)  # sefl.fn is play_url in your case
        except BaseException as e:
            self.future.set_exception(e)
        else:
            self.future.set_result(result)  # The result is set on the Future
```

As you can see, when the function is done, the result is set on the `Future` object. Because the `Future` object doesn't actually know anything about the function that *provided* the result, there is no way to attempt to re-run the function using the `Future` object. All you could do is return the `url` along with the `1` when the timeout occurs, and then re-`submit` the url to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
def player_url(url):
    # here. if timeout, return 1. otherwise do I/O and return 0.
    ...
    if timeout:
        return (1, url)
    else:
        return (0, url)

urls = [...]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    while urls:
        future_to_url = executor.map(player_url, urls)
        urls = []  # Clear urls list, we'll re-add any timed out operations.
        for future in future_to_url:
            if future.result()[0] == 1:
                urls.append(future.result()[1]) # stick url into list
```

Comment: Just one minor problem, if you use `executor.map(player_url, urls)`, later will raise `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_condition'`. I use the original way and works fine.

Comment: @xiang Ah, sorry. I've corrected that error. `as_completed` shouldn't be used with the iterator returned by `map`. Using the original approach you had is fine, too. This way is just a bit more succinct.